# Hide Email2Case email for specific User Roles

Tags: apex, trigger, email, email2case

We are using different Email2case for different teams.
[image]

The thing is that only specific teams should be able to see them for example Austria team will need to see Sales.austria@selina.com but not Sales.portugal@selina.com

How can we display specific email2case to specific roles ?

I did not find any out of the box solution, so maybe some custom code .. but did not find any guidance here ..

thx you very much
Raf

Comment: What is the owd setting for case object?

Comment: It is public read-only, since I want anyone to be able to see what happened with the customer